# Proof of equality based on polynomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$a x^2 + bx + c = 0 \rightarrow$ roots are $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
$Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0 \rightarrow$ rootsa re $\alpha$ $+$ $\delta$ and $\beta$ $+$ $\delta$.

### Prove that $\frac{b^2 - 4ac}{a^2}$ $=$$\frac{B^2 - 4AC}{A^2}$.

How to go about this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$, then the discriminant is given by

$$(\alpha-\beta)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general if the roots of a quadratic equation are $r_1$ and $r_2$, then the quadratic can be written as
$$x^2 - (r_1+r_2) x+r_1r_2=0$$
In other words if you have a quadratic $ax^2 + bx+ c= 0$, with roots $\alpha, \beta$, then $\alpha + \beta = -b/a$ and $\alpha\beta = c/a$.
Can you finish the job now?

Comment: But the coefficient of the leading term is A not 1.

Comment: You can divide by $A$ to get $A=1$.

Comment: the l.h.s simplifies to (alpha)^2 + (beta)^2 + (alpha * beta)

Comment: But the r.h.s does not simplify to be equal to the l.h.s.

Comment: Actually I just assumed your proposition is correct and gave the method to solve it. But what you want to prove is wrong. Take for the first quadratic $x^2=0$ ($a=1$, $b=c=0$) with $\alpha = \beta= 0$. And for the second $(x-1)^2$ ($a=1=c$, $b=-2$), with roots $\alpha + \delta =0+1$ and $\beta + \delta=0+1 $ ($\delta$ being 1). If you check your proposition fails even for this simple case.

Comment: in your question i think you need to prove $\frac{b^2-4ac}{a^2}=\frac{B^2-4AC}{A^2}$

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: Now how to go about it?

Comment: ok then follow my hint

Comment: Thankyou I got it. (for b^2 - 4 ac  )

Answer (score 0):

The roots of a quadratic are such that $\alpha+\beta={-b\over a}$ and $\alpha\beta={c\over a}$. One has $d^2=\left(\alpha-\beta\right)^2=\left(\alpha+\beta\right)^2-4\alpha\beta$. So

$$d^2=\left({b\over a}\right)^2-4{c\over a}={b^2-4ac\over a^2}$$

And we have $\alpha+\delta-\beta-\delta=\alpha-\beta$